# Silly doubt on Cherenkov radiation and QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, casimir-effect, cherenkov-radiation

Firstly, consider the casimir effect. A interesting feature of this effect is that an attractive force appears which is generated by negative energy. This attractive force arises because the renormalized energy is given by:

$$E^{\mathrm{Casimir}}(a) = -\frac{\hbar c\pi S}{720 a}. $$

My question is: for Cherenkov radiation exists a "renormalized energy"? In other words, for Cherenkov radiation exists a "$E^{\mathrm{Cherenkov}}(a)$"?

Comment: No, it's a classical effect, like a shock wave in gas, for example.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski that would be strange to ask but: there are other physical effects that results in "nice energy densities" like Casimir? Would you give me another example of "$E^{\mathrm{Some}\mathrm{Other}\mathrm{Effect}}(a)$"?